# Exibir dados em uma mesma linha

Tags: php, html

Olá! Tenho uma tabela setando outra tabela e estou tentando exibir um mesmo conteúdo setado na mesma linha.

Fiz um while mas o resultado tá ficando assim:

> ```
> André Cargo: Operário
> André Cargo: Auxiliar
> Julia Cargo: Secretária
> Julia Cargo: Auxiliar
> ```

Tô querendo que fique assim:

> ```
> André Cargo: Operário e Auxiliar
> Julia Cargo: Secretária e Auxiliar
> ```

```
$sql = "select * from funcionarios join cargos on funcionarios.id = cargos.id_funcionario";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  ?>

    <div class="card-stacked">
    <div class="card-content">
      <strong><?php echo $row['nome']; ?></strong>
      <p>Cargo: <?php echo $row['cargo']; ?></p>
  </div>
  </div>


 <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Precisa colocar o seu código SQL ou PHP para saber exatamente onde mexer.

Comment: Coloquei o código.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a função `GROUP_CONCAT` juntamente com o `GROUP BY` no `MySQL`:

```
<?php
    $sql = "
        select funcionarios.nome, group_concat(cargos.cargo) as cargo from funcionarios
        join cargos on funcionarios.id = cargos.id_funcionario
        group by funcionarios.id
    ";

    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        ?>
            <div class="card-stacked">
                <div class="card-content">
                    <strong><?php echo $row['nome']; ?></strong>
                    <p>Cargo: <?php echo $row['cargo']; ?></p>
                </div>
            </div>    
        <?php
    }
?>
```

**EDIT:**

Para você limitar a quantidade de cargos por funcionário, terá que trocar seu `SELECT` para isso:

```
select funcionarios.nome, (
    select group_concat(cargo) from cargos
    where id_funcionario = funcionarios.id
    limit 2
) as cargo
from funcionarios
```

Comment: Era isso mesmo. No caso agr como eu faria pra limitar os cargos pra mostrar só 2 por pessoa?

Comment: Editei a resposta colocando o limite.